# Wordpress Home page modification

Tags: customization

I have recently started  using wordpress and currently i am using version 4.2.2..I am stuck at my home page ..I dont know how to remove that portion which i have highlited in the picture below(basically i want my home pate to be BLANK). So can u guys help me by removing all of these...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking.  You don't want anything on the homepage of your site?  You can remove the widgets (the left side) in Appearance > Widgets in your admin. The Leave a Reply box looks like comments, which can usually be turned of on a page or post.